# Flyway multiple schema dependencies

Tags: flyway

How does Flyway handle multiple schema dependencies?

Ie 
`V1_CREATE_TABLE.sql` in `SCHEMA_A`

`V2_CREATE_VIEW.sql` in `SCHEMA_B` (based on table in schema A)

Is it possible to ensure that V1 is created before V2?

It is also possible to get into a cross dependency. For example say `V3_CREATE_VIEW_2.sql` in `SCHEMA_A` (based on view in schema B). How do we ensure that dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway will execute the scripts in order based on their version numbers. If you want a single instance of Flyway to manage objects in multiple schemas, you must prefix the object names in the migration scripts.

Comment: Can you provide a prefix example for multiple schemas?

Comment: Right I see now, you have to prefix the table IN the script, and not in the file name itself.